# Eclipse : debugging an Java class in Eclipse IDE , under Debugger perspective

Tags: eclipse

I am debugging an Java class in Eclipse IDe, , i have 
put several break points for it .

While debugging the Application , the following is shown under debug view 
please see the screen shot here .
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dnga68&s=7

What i am expecting i that when i press F6 , it should go to next line and when i  press F8 should go to  next break point .
But why this stepping views are shown ??

( During this view should we press F6 or F8 so that it goes to the java source ??)

Please guide me i am new to debugging in Eclipse .

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is suspended inside some of the JUnit library code, for which you do not have source code. There's no way the debugger can show you the source if you don't have it! You can see where the program is stopped by looking at the stack trace; the method named at the very top is the current method.

You can press the green arrow to run until you hit the next breakpoint, which is presumably inside code for which you *do* have the source.

Comment: Thank you very much ,please tell me which green button you were actually referring to ??

Comment: You see the large window at the top which says "Debug" on one tab and "Servers" on the other tab at the left? At the right end of that same window frame, there are a bunch of buttons which are the debugging control panel. The green triangle with a little yellow box below it is the "Run until breakpoint" button. The next two are pause and stop, then disconnect, then several different variations of stepping.

Comment: Thank you very much , you mean that Resume F8 button ??